# Why is the System.IO.File class static

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io

I was wondering why is the `File` class static?

There are some methods that makes sense to be static like `Create`.
But, when I want to move a file I preffer to just specify the new location. The same applies to `Copy`, `Open` and more. I guessed this issue was already discussed somewhere, but a search didn't give any results but a general thread of why to create static methods.

I don't say that all the methods in `File` shouldn't be static, but there sure are methods that should be instance-related.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which has instance methods like [`CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0e105zt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`MoveTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But if you are performing single operation on file then it will be more efficient to use static methods of [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class instead of creating instance `FileInfo` object. If you are performing multiple operations, then creating `FileInfo` will allow to skip additional security checks. Actually `File` is kind of service, which manipulates files. Maybe class name is not the best one.

Comment: I had no idea that class exists. It's a weird name for such a class

Comment: Indeed, and if OP had simply [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.100).aspx) he would have found this: "The static methods of the File class perform security checks on all methods. If you are going to reuse an object several times, consider using the corresponding instance method of FileInfo instead, because the security check will not always be necessary"

Comment: They had obviously already used the name "File" for the static class, so "FileInfo" was the best they could come up with. Naming things can be really hard sometimes, just because there are not enough suitable words.

Answer (score 0):

`File` is static probably because `File` is only concerned about creating a connection to the (*logical*) contents of the (*physical*) file. `FileStream` on the other hand is not static, because it represents the data that can be read from the file. Think of `File` as referring to an address, where `FileStream` focuses on the *content* of said address the address. If you think about the separation between the physical container, and the logical contents, the separation begins to make more sense - singleton access to the container, but individualized access to the contents of each container you attach.